# Disappearing content c++ writing to file

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

Whenever I write the data into the file after rerunning the code the contents of the file disappears

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main(){
    string username = "";
    string path = "/Users/kishorejyothi/Desktop/C++/practice/list_usernames.txt";
    ofstream file(path);

    if(file.fail()){
        cerr << "Failed process";
        exit(1);
    }

    cout << "Enter a username: ";
    cin >> username;

    string full_username = username.append("@Abhinav.com");


    if(username.empty()){
        cout << "You didn't enter your username";
    }
    else{
        cout << "Thanks for entering your preferred username." << endl;
        cout << "Your username is now " << full_username;
    }
    file << username << endl;

    file.close();
}
```

I was exxpecting the file to write the usernames on seperaate lines of code.

Comment: What do you enter, what file content do you expect, what actual content is there - please show all this information in the question, otherwise it's unclear.

Comment: Whenever you open the file, all its current contents will be lost. That's because you don't open in in in a read-write or append mode. That's how the file streams are specified to work. That's really how *all* file API's work: You need to tell the system that you want to keep the current contents, otherwise it will be lost.

Comment: If you're serious about learning C++, then please invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), which will teach you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 4):

the default open mode deletes the file content, open the file in `append` mode if you want it to keep its previous content.

```cpp
ofstream file(path, std::ios::app);
```